# Epsilon closure & automata

Tags: math, computer-science, automata, non-deterministic, epsilon

I think I do not quite understand the concept of epsilon transitions
when determining the language of a non-deterministic automata.
For example in this automata:

[image: automata-with-epsilon-transitions]

The language is: 'A double sequence of `a` or a double sequence of `b` where there is a possibility of a `baa` sequence'.

But, the word `a` belongs to the automata too, doesn't it? (also the word `b`, and `aaa` and so on...)

Comment: You are right, `a,b,aaa,bbb,aa..` are acceptable strings for this automaton, probably the description is not fully correct.

Comment: okay! that's a relief...thank you!

Comment: What’s the source of the explanation of the automaton’s language? That looks incorrect to me.

Comment: As written, this NFA accepts (a|b)* -- also it is very unusual to combine epsilon transitions with normal transitions.  I think those a,ε and b,ε transitions are probably mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *ε-transition* is just a impromptu transition which doesn't consume any input.

When you are in a state which has outgoing *ε-transitions* it's like being in all of them until the automaton does something which is observable, from here the non determinism. The set of such states is the ε-closure of a state.

According to the layout you can have an arbitrary amount of `baa` prefixes followed by an arbitrary amount of of `a`s or `b`s. So:

- *empty*
- baa
- baabaa
- a
- aa
- ba
- abab
- baabab
- ...

Comment: Thank you! i have another question if i may, regarding epsilon transitions- in this picture i sent, if i want to turn it to 'DFA' automata - is their any method that make it happend?

Comment: It's always possible to convert a NFA to a DFA, there are multiple algorithms for this, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)'s one